# how to calculate the translateX value using scale X

Tags: javascript, svg, transform, scale

I am trying to calculate the translateX value using scale x. I have set the transform to the element using some calculation. let see the example,

```
<svg width="31" height="31">
    <rect x="12" y="-10" width="20" height="20" transform="translate(2.5862203480096,16.25) scale(1.646346038331595 1)" />
</svg>
```

here i have set the transform. this was fine.. if i remove scaleX(1.6463).. it will be not correct. i need to find the exact output without using the scaleX and scaleY... how to calculate this using those value(there is any formula or calculation)?

translateX = 2.5862203480096
scaleX = 1.646346038331595

using those value i need to find the exact tranlsateX..

https://jsfiddle.net/0em3Lpxo/2/

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you restate it more clearly, otherwise it will most likely be closed.